# Laravel 5.4 Undefined Variable from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I recently got started with Laravel 5.4, I'm familiar with 5.3. I'm trying to pass a variable from my controller to the view and keep getting an "Undefined variable $savedStores".

```
public function index()
{
    //

    $stores = Store::where('id as user_id')->get();

    return view('home')->with('savedStores', $store);
}
```

That is my controller code.

In my view, I have

```
             @if(count($savedStores)>0)

              @foreach($savesStores as $savedStore)
              <p>{{$savedStore -> name}}</p>

              @endforeach




              @endif
```

Comment: Provide the exact error message; it currently sounds like it complains about an undefined variable named $error which you havn't included in your question.

Comment: Turns out I had an error in my routes which redefined the view for the 'home' route. I have figured it out and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually with method used for session data.

You can pass variables to view.

```
return view('home',['savedStores'=>$stores]);
```

or

```
return view('home',compact('stores')); // as store variable.
```

Comment: Will try this now and get back to you

Comment: have checked is there values in the variable before return to view

Comment: Hey, doesn't seem to work. Is there anyway to check if 'code' $stores = Store::where('id as user_id')->get(); actually works?

Comment: Store::find($id); or Store::where('id',$id)->first(); you can use dd($stores); to check is there any records.

Comment: Thanks @xuma how do I pass data to the $id variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('home',['savedStores'=>$stores]);
```

spelling mistake chane $store to $stores

Comment: This is also not working. Is there anyway to test my query or simplify it to display all stores?

Comment: I agree @ashranrupashinghe. I can't however, figure out how to pass data to the query. Can you help with that please?

Comment: added new answer, can you check that

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code:

from:

```
$stores = Store::where('id as user_id')->get();
```

to:

```
$stores = Store::where('id',$some_id_value)->get();
```

Or you can get all store records by:

```
$stores = Store::all();
```

You are passing the variable to view in correct manner.

More details check here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views

Comment: Thank you. How do I pass data to the $some_id_value? Please note in my table, the column I'm trying to search through is user_id

Comment: @OlabinjoAdeniran so you can use it like $stores = Store::where('user_id','user id for which you need to find details')->get();

Comment: Yes I get that @SagarArora but I'm wondering how to get data into that parameter. Doesn't seem to be working as it is

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
public function index()
{

    $stores = Store::select('*','id as user_id')->get();
    dd($stores);//see query result, if you get correct result here, just remove this line
    return view('home')->with('savedStores', $stores );
}
```